# ListFragment vs ListActivity - Which one to use?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Could someone tell me which one should I use? I mean in terms of "best practice".
Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html Please check this link to know how list fragment used with listview

Comment: I read descriptions of both ListActivity and ListFragment, but I couldn't see anything that says that one is better than other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have tablet design in mind, you should probably use listfragment instead of listactivity. You can still easily wrap fragment in a activity for phone design. Developing app using fragment is a good design pattern. you can read more in here.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html